# Use Makefile in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, makefile

I am writing a C++ project and trying to use a makefile that is already written. It seems that the project builds in Xcode, but I dont see any file appearing in the file obj. Here is my makefile code:

```
INCLDIR := include
OBJDIR  := obj
SRCDIR  := src
BINDIR  := bin

CC      := g++
VPATH   :=
LDFLAGS :=
LIBRARY :=
CFLAGS  := -g -Wall -I $(INCLDIR)

#Source and object files (automatic)
SRCS = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
OBJS = $(subst $(SRCDIR)/,$(OBJDIR)/, $(subst .cpp,.o, $(SRCS)))

# Define here your main source files separated by spaces (without suffix!)
EXEC = main

#Phony = do not represent a file
#.PHONY: all
all : makedir $(EXEC)

# For multiple binaries
$(EXEC) : %: %.cpp $(OBJS)
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BINDIR)/$@ $^ 

$(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $< 

#Clean: delete every binaries and object files
.PHONY: clean
clean :
rm -rf $(OBJDIR)/*
rm -rf $(BINDIR)/*
#Building folders (-p : no error if folder do not exist)
.PHONY: makedir
makedir :
mkdir -p $(BINDIR)
mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)

#For some debug
.PHONY: print
print :
echo $(SRCS)
echo $(OBJS)
```

[And here are the folders I have for the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh6it.png)

Comment: As usual, with any "my code doesn't work" problem, you need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: *I dont see any file appearing in the file obj* What do you mean under file appearing in file?

Comment: Does Xcode use makefiles? Does it give you messages of any kind when you run it?

Comment: It should, but I think there is an error in my make file. Now I get the error message "Makefile:25: *** missing separator.  Stop."